# Having trouble understanding how tensorflow probability Bijectors 'RealNVP' 'log_prob works

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

Here's the code

```
tfd = tfp.distributions
tfb = tfp.bijectors

# A common choice for a normalizing flow is to use a Gaussian for the base
# distribution. (However, any continuous distribution would work.) E.g.,
nvp = tfd.TransformedDistribution(
    distribution=tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=[0., 0., 0.]),
    bijector=tfb.RealNVP(
        num_masked=2,
        shift_and_log_scale_fn=tfb.real_nvp_default_template(
            hidden_layers=[512, 512])))

x = nvp.sample((32,32))
```

`x = nvp.sample((32,32))` gives me a tensor with `32x32x3`shape . But when throwing the `x` into `nvp.log_prob(x)`, I get a `32x32`shape tensor. I was expecting a `(1,)`like tensor since I want to get `log_prob` of this `32,32,3` tensor.

So the problem is, how to tinker the code above to calculate `log_prob` of a `32x32x3`-shape tensor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RNVP transforms vector-valued distributions (i.e. MVNDiag in your case above). You can try `nvp.distribution.log_prob(x)` (apply the underlying distribution's `log_prob`), and note that it has the same shape. The `log_prob` function "consumes" the event shape of `x`.

The `log_prob` of a transformed distribution is something like

`nvp.distribution.log_prob(nvp.bijector.inverse(x)) - nvp.bijector.inverse_log_det_jacobian(x)` (I may have the sign swapped.)

Namely, it is the sum of the underlying distribution's `log_prob` applied to the samples pulled back through the bijective transformation plus a correction term to account for the (local, at `x`) change in volume induced by the bijective transformation.

Comment: To add to this, I'd suggest having a look at the TFP Shapes colab: https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/jupyter_notebooks/Understanding_TensorFlow_Distributions_Shapes.ipynb